# Show a function is Sobolev

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method

Let $T_{h}$ be a subdivision of a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ into elements $K$ with boundary $\delta K$so that the Gauss divergence theorem holds.

If for a function $f$ it holds that $f \in C(\bar \Omega)$ such that $f \in C^\infty(\bar K)$ for all $K \in T_h$, then $f \in W^{1,2}( \Omega)$.

I am fairly new to this topic. Can anyone please help/explain/give me an idea how to show this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show that $f \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, we have to show that it possesses weak derivatives. Recall that $v_i$ is $\partial_i f$ (in a weak sense), if
$$\int_\Omega f \, \partial_i \varphi \, \mathrm{d}x = - \int_\Omega v_i \, \varphi \, \mathrm{d}x$$
for all $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$. Now, let $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ be given. We have
$$\int_\Omega f \, \partial_i \varphi \, \mathrm{d}x = \sum_K \int_K f \, \partial_i \varphi \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Now, you should

- use Gauß divergence theorem on each $K$
- utilize that $K$ is a subdivision to get rid of the boundary integrals over $\delta K$
- write everything as an integral over $\Omega$.

If everything works, you arrive at
$$\int_\Omega f \, \partial_i \varphi \, \mathrm{d}x = -\int_\Omega \partial_i f \, \varphi \, \mathrm{d} x,$$
where $\partial f_i$ is defined piecewise on each element $K$.

Comment: How do we conclude that the test function $\varphi$ is $0$ on the parts of $\delta K$ which do not coincide with $\delta \Omega$?

Comment: $\varphi$ is not $0$ there, but each "part" of $\delta K$ is the boundary of two different elements. Try to add the corresponding integrals.